Density matrix $\rho = I/2$ implies an ensemble of orthonormal states
Suppose that a density matrix $\rho = I/2$ is obtained as a description of an ensemble of two pure states. How can I show that the ensemble must then be of the form:
$$
\{(|\psi\rangle, 1/2), (|\psi^\perp\rangle, 1/2)\}
$$
where $|\psi\rangle$ is a pure state and $|\psi^\perp\rangle$ is a pure state orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$?

I've tried considering any ensemble
$$
\mathsf E = \{(|\psi_1\rangle, p_1), \cdots, (|\psi_n\rangle, p_n)\}
$$
and then
$$
\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle \psi_i |
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle\phi|\rho |\phi\rangle &= \sum_i p_i \langle \phi|\psi_i\rangle \langle\psi_i | \phi\rangle \\
&= \sum_i p_i |\langle \phi|\psi_i\rangle|^2
\end{aligned}
$$
but can't work out where to go from here (or if I should be here in the first place). I only have a very basic understanding of density matrices so would appreciate an elementary explanation. Thanks!

related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17060/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21099/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21623/55

As stated at the beginning of your post let us assume there exist state vectors $\psi_1,\psi_2\in\mathbb C^2$ (i.e. $\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle=\langle\psi_2|\psi_2\rangle=1$) and $p_1,p_2\in[0,1]$ such that
$$
\tfrac{I}2=p_1|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|+p_2|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|\,.\tag1
$$
Our goal is to show that $p_1=p_2=\frac12$ and $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=0$, and we shall do so in two steps.
Step 1: $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=0$
Taking the trace of (1) yields
\begin{align*}
1={\rm tr}(\tfrac I2)&=p_1{\rm tr}(|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|)+p_2{\rm tr}(|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|)\\
&=p_1\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle+p_2\langle\psi_2|\psi_2\rangle\\
&=p_1+p_2\,.\tag2
\end{align*}
On the other hand
\begin{align*}
\tfrac12\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle&=\langle\psi_1|\tfrac I2|\psi_2\rangle\\
&\overset{\text{(1)}}=\big\langle\psi_1\big|\;  p_1|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|+p_2|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|  \;\big|\psi_2\big\rangle\\
&=p_1\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle+p_2\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle\langle\psi_2|\psi_2\rangle\\
&=(p_1+p_2)\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle\\
&\overset{\text{(2)}}=\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle
\end{align*}
But $\tfrac12\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle$ is only possible if $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=0$, as desired.
Step 2: $p_1=p_2=\frac12$
This is now easy because we can just take expectation values of (1):
$$
\tfrac12=\tfrac12\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle=\langle\psi_1|\tfrac{I}2|\psi_1\rangle\overset{\text{(1)}}=p_1+p_2|\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle|^2\overset{\text{Step 1}}=p_1
$$
and similarly for $p_2$.

Thanks! Why may we assume that there are only two state vectors in the ensemble?

@OllyBritton That's what you ask to assume in your question!

@NorbertSchuch Ah! Yes of course.
